# Как добавить opacity градиента в мой градиент?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, linear-gradient

В моем макете полосы имеют эффект `opacity` градиента от прозрачного до полупрозрачного.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В настоящее время у меня получилось так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать так, чтобы белые полосы имели градиент прозрачности?

Вот мой текущий код:

```css
 body {
      background: gray;
    }

    .bar {
      height: 50px;
      width: 100%;
      background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #FC0252 0%, #01Fdd9 100%);
      border-radius: 100rem;
      position: relative;
    }
    /** Stripes. */
    .bar::before {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      border-radius: 100rem;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      background-size: 90px 100%;
      background-image: linear-gradient(
        120deg,
        transparent,
        transparent 40%,
        white 40%,
        white 60%,
        transparent 60%
      );
    }
```

```html
<div class="bar"></div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [How to put gradient opacity in my gradient?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62942698/7394871) от участника  [@Ramil Amparo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7569893/ramil-amparo).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/62942698/7394871

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете добавить слой маски на псевдоэлемент:

```css
body {
  background: gray;
}

.bar {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #FC0252 0%, #01Fdd9 100%);
  border-radius: 100rem;
  position: relative;
}


/** Stripes. */

.bar::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 100rem;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: 90px 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient( 120deg, transparent 40%, white 41% 60%, transparent 61%);
  -webkit-mask:linear-gradient(white,transparent);
          mask:linear-gradient(white,transparent);
}
```

```html
<div class="bar"></div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62942800/7394871) от участника  [@Temani Afif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif).</sub>